# Python ignore lines with multiple pattern match

Tags: python, list, string-matching

I have a list as below:

```
Index1_list=['ATTACTCG','TCCGGAGA','CGCTCATT','GAGATTCC','ATTCAGAA']
```

What I want to do is to save lines if lines only have one of the list elements inside `(not two different or three different)`

```
>seq1
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNATTACTCGNNNNNNNNNNNGAGATTCCNNNNN
>seq2
NNNNNNNNNNNNNATTACTCGNNNNNNNNNN
>seq3
NNNNNNNNNNNNNGAGATTCCNNNNNNNNNNN
```

the output should be

```
>seq2
NNNNNNNNNNNNNATTACTCGNNNNNNNNNN
>seq3
NNNNNNNNNNNNNGAGATTCCNNNNNNNNNNN
```

I used the script below but have not been able to filter out reads with two different matches.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

Index1_list=['ATTACTCG','TCCGGAGA','CGCTCATT','GAGATTCC','ATTCAGAA']


with open('All.fastq','r') as R1:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(R1,'fasta'):
        for i in Index1_list:
            if i in record.seq:
                sequences = record.format('fasta')
                print(sequences)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want by checking how many elements from your list are in the desired string, like this:

```python
from Bio import SeqIO

Index1_list=['ATTACTCG','TCCGGAGA','CGCTCATT','GAGATTCC','ATTCAGAA']


with open('All.fastq','r') as R1:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(R1,'fasta'):
        count = 0

        for i in Index1_list:
            if i in record.seq:
                count += 1

        if count == 1:
            sequences = record.format('fasta')
            print(sequences)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a question regarding the counter - please correct me if I am wrong, so the counter is actually for the ```record.seq``` which if it has been in the second for loop for two times ```(if the condition applies)``` then it means I have two indexes in that record.

Comment: Yes. The second for loop goes through `Index1_list`. For each element in the list, we test whether this element is present in `record.seq`. If this is the case, we increment the counter. Hence, the counter counts how many different elements from `Index1_list` are present in `record.seq`. Thus, we only want to print it if the counter is equal to `1`. Note that we only test whether an element from the list is present at least once in `record.seq`, we do not know how many times it is present. Hence, `"NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNATTACTCGNNNNNNNNNNNATTACTCGNNNNN"` would be printed as well.

Comment: That was a perfect and detailed answer, thank you so much for your help :)